# How to return first record and totalizers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I return first purchase date, first salesman and first store by customer along with his total expenses?

```
select 
    bi.biifclie as customer,
    aux.salesman as first_salesman,
    aux.store as first_store,
    aux.date_ as first_date,
    CAST(SUM(bi.biifpliq) as float64) as total_bought,
    CAST((SUM(bi.biifptab)-SUM(bi.biifpliq)) as float64) as discount,
    CAST(SUM(bi.biifpliq)-SUM(bi.biifcrep)-SUM(bi.biifvari + bi.biifcomb + bi.biifcomc + bi.biificmc)-SUM(bi.biiffixo) as float64) as rentability,
    COUNT(DISTINCT bi.biifcodi) AS orders
    MAX(bi.biifdata) AS last_purchase_date,
    MIN(bi.biifdata) AS first_purchase_date,
    DATE_DIFF(MAX(bi.biifdata),current_date(),month)*-1 as inactivity_time,
    FROM yyyyyyy.gix.bi_biif bi 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        aux0.biifclie as customer,
        aux0.biifvend as salesman,
        aux0.biifempe as store,
        aux0.biifdata as date_
        FROM yyyyyyy.gix.bi_biif aux0 ORDER BY date_ ASC LIMIT 1
    ) AS aux ON aux.cliente = bi.biifclie
    GROUP BY customer,first_salesman,first_store,first_date
```

I tried to do that using a left join sub query, ordering it by date (so that I can return the first date), but those fields (

```
aux.salesman as first_salesman,
aux.store as first_store,
aux.date_ as first_date,
```

)
all returned null

Am I doing smethng wrong or the logic is not correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Pleas include sufficient example data to demonstrate the behaviour you desire.  (Generally, it is best to simplify the problem to just the columns that are necessary to demonstrate that behaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select biifclie as customer,
  array_agg(struct(biifvend as salesman, biifempe  as store, biifdata as date) order by biifdata limit 1)[offset(0)].*,
  cast(sum(biifpliq) as float64) as total_bought
from `yyyyyyy.gix.bi_biif` t
group by customer
```

Above solution, does 1) grouping by customer 2) for each customer it takes all the respective rows and leaves the one - the first one ordered by date 3) than it "converts result from array to separate columns

Comment: Yep, it worked, thanks Mikhail, but could you explain in the other way, with left join? Your solution is good and I'll mark as anwser but Id like to understand and do the easiest way, since your method requires too much knowledge and i'm a beginner. Thanks

Comment: the way it is done in my answer  - IS the easiest and most optimal way to do what you asked. Doing it with joins is not effective and counter productive! Anyway - see brief explanation in answer

Comment: Yep, it helped and I upvoted, but since I'm rep 15- my upvote get not into account --edit just got 15 rep and upvoted.

Comment: What does [offset(0)].* does and what is it syntax? right after the agg_array?

Comment: result of array_agg is an array. because of limit 1 it is an array with one element. so `[offset(0)]` extracts this element as a struct. and then `.*` presents that struct as separate columns. you can see this by playing with code and removing `.*` and see result, then removing `[offset(0)]` and so on